# How to hide elements in jQuery until after the user starts scrolling

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I need to hide two divs `#top` and `#header-space` until the user begins scrolling the page. I have already tried to do so but this code still displays the two divs after the page has loaded. I am doing this within WordPress using jQuery and only want to do it for the homepage. Can't get past this point.

Here's the code I have tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        var y = $(window).scrollTop(0);
        var width = $(window).innerWidth();

        if(window.location.pathname == '/'){
            if ( window.innerWidth > 1000) {
                if( y > 0 ){
                    $('#top').fadeIn();
                    $('#header-space').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $('#top').fadeOut();
                    $('#header-space').fadeOut();
                }
            }
        } else {
        }   
    });
});
```

Comment: Think it through - you've stated it perfectly here: *I need to hide two divs #top and #header-space until the user begins scrolling the page*.  The code you've shown us *shows* some element once you scroll.  But they need to be hidden before that, right?  Then need to be hidden initially. So how would you do that? :-) Just have the default CSS hide them!

Comment: @Don'tPanic hiding the divs using CSS got the code working but after removing the code that restricts it to the homepage & viewport. But I need these. Maybe my if statements are incorrect.`jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(window).on('scroll', function(){
            var y = $(window).scrollTop();
            if( y > 0 ){
                    $('#top').fadeIn();
                    $('#header-space').fadeIn();
            } else {
                    $('#top').fadeOut();
                    $('#header-space').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });`

Comment: Um ... you're welcome? :-) As to the conditions, get debugging! `console.log(window.location.pathname)`,  `console.log(window.innerWidth)`, `console.log('y is', y, 'width is', width)` ... etc.  Work out which of them is not right, adjust, tune ... debug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code out:

```
var position = $(window).scrollTop(); 
// should start at 0

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > position) {
        // Code to for Scrolling Down
    } else {
         // Code to for Scrolling Up
    }
    position = scroll;
});
```

You can delete the 'IF' statement and make the code run on any case. or only place your code on the first condition which is triggered when the user scrolls down.